# duvidas intercalação de vetores em C

Tags: c

olá, eu tenho um problema aqui com vetores gostaria de intender o que esta dando de errado e estou tendo dificuldades, se alguem puder me ajudar sobre isso.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int vet1[5], vet2[5], rvet[10];
    int i, j, k, n1=0, n2=0, aux=0;


    for(i=0; i<=4; i++)//Lê o vet1
    {

        printf("Digite para posicao %d do vet1:\n", n1++);
        scanf("%i", &vet1[i]);
    }

    printf("Obrigado, agora:\n");

    for(j=0; j<=4; j++)//Lê vet2
    {
        printf("Digite para posicao %d do vet1:\n", n2++);
        scanf("%d", &vet2[j]);

    }


    for(k=0;k<=9;k++)//Intercala os vetores
    {
        if(k%2=0)//separa valor de k em par
        {
            rvet[k]=vet1[i];
        }

        if(k%2!=0)//separa valor de k em impar
        {
            rvet[k]=vet2[j];
        }
    }

    for(k=0; k<=9; k++)
    {
        printf("vet[%d]:%d\n", k, rvet[k]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Defina o que você quer dizer com "está dando errado". Isso é muito vago. O código não compila? (qual o erro?) O resultado não é o que você esperava? (qual a resposta do programa? qual a esperada? qual foi a entrada?)

Comment: Leonardo, as pessoas neste site ajudam porque querem. O mínimo que você pode fazer é ser educado com os outros. Pedir "leia meu código e descubra todos os problemas" não é uma boa ideia.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Amigo**, encontrei *alguns erros* em seu código, alguns que tornam o algoritmo inválido, outros erros menores e um que economiza memória no caso de programação para dispositivos embarcados (que provavelmente não é o seu caso) ou em programas gigantescos. Então vejamos:

**1 - Erros menores:**

No segundo `for`, o `printf()` informa `vet1` e não `vet2`. Não é um erro no código mas não está certo. Se não quiser, não precisa corrigir mas deveria.

**2 - Economia de memória**

Não há necessidade de haver uma variável para cada `for`, que no caso são `i`, `j` e `k`. Isso pois tu sempre zera a variável utilizada, como em `for(i=0; i<=4; i++){ ... }`.

Traduzindo: tu pode utilizar `i` em todos os `for` que fores utilizar, mudando os locais necessários. E isto só não é verdade se precisares do valor dessas variáveis posteriormente para alguma outra tarefa. Aí sim as criará - o que não é o caso.

Digo isso, pois, em sistemas embarcados, cada 'pedaço' de memória é importante. E ações como esta no código de aplicações de grande porte - que tu provavelmente desenvolverá ou ajudará a desenvolver - se acumulam e causam um gasto horrendo de memória!

**3 - Erro de algoritmo (e sintaxe):**

Na seção de código em que tu intercala os valores dos vetores, mais precisamente no primeiro `if`, há um erro de sintaxe que causa um erro no algoritmo; veja:

```
    if(k%2=0)//separa valor de k em par
    {
        rvet[k]=vet1[i];
    }
```

Quando desejar comparar dois valores em uma igualdade, você deve utilizar o sinal `==`. Já o sinal `=`, irás utilizar para atribuição.

Para evitar estes erros futuramente, utilize espaços sempre que possível e for permitido, como por exemplo `if(k % 2 == 0)`. Ajuda a visualizar melhor o código. Melhor ainda seria utilizar `if( (k % 2) == 0 )`.

**4 - Extras**

- Ainda sobre a intercalação de valores: você não precisa utilizar dois `if` neste algoritmo. Basta utilizar um `else` e o motivo é simples: se um número não é par, é só pode ser ímpar! Assim, pode trocar `if(k%2!=0)` por `else`.
- Quando for colocar sua dúvida no **Stack Overflow** ou em qualquer outro lugar, procure sempre informar as mensagens de erro e os avisos pós compilação. Eles ajudam a entender o erro. E com o tempo tu irá perceber que eles são ótimos aliados dos programadores!

Comment: Nossa concerteza eu mando porem nem warning tinha Sr. José, obrigado pela resposta. queria manter contato se tiver como.

Comment: esqueci de avisar eu ja tinha mudado o programa e ele esta funcionando tentei usar suas dicas porem nao concegui mas irei discutir com minha professora hoje.

Comment: Bom, compilador algum irá gerar warnings sobre a melhor forma de escrever um código para fácil manutenção. As boas práticas de programação sempre pedem que se escreva um código que seja fácil de ser lido por terceiros e por ti, claro. :)

Answer (score 3):

Tem alguns erros seu código, tente algo assim:

```
i = j = 0;
for(k= 0; k < 10; k++)//Intercala os vetores
  rvet[k] = k % 2 == 0 ? vet1[i++] : vet2[j++];
```

Comment: gabriel eu tenho uma duvida, por que o i=j=0, o resto entendi e deu certo muito obrigado =)

Comment: Por que ele irá utilizar posteriormente na Operação Ternária ([link](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera%C3%A7%C3%A3o_tern%C3%A1ria)). No caso, ele precisa acessar inicialmente a posição 0 de cada um dos vetores - é também um bom exemplo mais curto de programa e que utilize `i`, `j` e `k` sabiamente. Nota: esta sintaxe `i = j = 0` não é errada mas não é muito indicada como boa prática de programação (onde seu código será lido por outros). É melhor separar em atribuições diferentes.